# What are signal traps?

Tags: signals, trap

Signals are the way of communication between process but I have some questions 
What are signal traps?  How the traps are related to signals in operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes an example is worth more than a thousand words:
This code in c++ exposes a very simple signal handler.

```
void gracefullShutdown(int sigNum) { 

    // cleanup or do wathever you need to do in case of received signal(s)

    // Terminate this executable
    exit(sigNum);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    signal(SIGINT , gracefullShutdown); 
    signal(SIGTERM , gracefullShutdown);

    std::cout << "starting..." << std::endl;

    while(1);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When you press the Ctrl+C during execution of this program, the linux kernel will send a SIGINT signal to this program, normally it would terminate, but in this precise case it leaves you the possibility to do something before terminating.

Answer (score 1):

To "trap a signal" (also called *install a signal handler*) is do something when the signal is received.  Here's a little shell script to illustrate:

```
#!/bin/sh

bye() {
    echo bye
    exit 1
}

trap bye SIGUSR1

echo hello

for Y in $(jot 80)
do
    printf '.'
    sleep 1
done

echo not reached
```

Executed:

```
$ shtrap & { sleep 3 && kill -s SIGUSR1 $!; }
[2] 22471
hello
...[1]   User defined signal 1   sleep 1
bye
```

We start the script as a background process, wait 3 seconds, and raise the SIGUSR1 signal with `kill`.  The script traps that signal, and invokes its `bye` function.

The operating system defines default behavior for each signal.  By trapping it, the program can change the default.  Daemons often trap SIGHUP this way to force re-reading of a configuration file while the program is running.